# How to redirect returning users who previously logged in?

Tags: redirect, logout

There are many answers to how to redirect after login. But my situation is different.
In my scenario, we have a landing page where people can login. Once logged in, the users are not logged out for a year. So, what we want to do is, when the user visits the site, check if they are logged in. If they are logged in, automatically redirect to a specific page.
I used a plugin to embed this code on the landing page, but it does nothing :

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
wp_redirect( 'https://our.domain/specific-page/' );
exit;
}
```

**Edit:**  I added echo statements before entering the if block, after entering the block, after calling wp_redirect, and, after exit.
When I look at the page source, all the echos are printing, except the one after exit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links can help you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191359/how-to-change-session-expire-time-in-wordpress
- https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-redirect-users-after-successful-login-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks but no. I have already taken care of the session expiry. The second one, I'm talking about a returning user. Not a user who logs in right now.

Comment: Then try debugging why it's not working. `if(is_user_logged_in()){ echo 123; die(); }` does this show something?

Comment: It does not echo anything.

Comment: where have you placed the code? Is there caching on the website? try first lines from functions.php in your theme

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with PHP, but I suspected this has something to do with headers. If I embed the script in a page, it is trying to redirect AFTER the page is rendered. So, I used a plugin called Code Snippets to add this to the functions.php:

```
function my_custom_function() {
    if(is_front_page()){ 
        echo "before the block";
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            echo "user is logged in";
         wp_redirect( "https://my.domain/page/");
            echo "after redirect";
          exit;
            echo "after exit";
    }
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_function' );
```